# Why am I getting a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error for array of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm using a dynamic array of pointers. The project requires this setup. When I execute, I get an error that the pointer being freed was not allocated.

Updated to add dynamic code. Functions throw bad access errors when I attempt to access the array, and seg faults from deleting the dynamic array.

```
class Person
{
private:
string firstName;
string lastName;
int age;
int telNum;
int numAddrs;
//Address* addrs[10];
Address* addrs;

public:
Person(string, string, int, int);
Person();
Person(const Person &p);

~Person();

void setFirstName(string);
void setLastName(string);
void setAge(int);
void setTelNum(int);
void setAddress(Address*);
void setNumAddrs(int);

string getFirstName();
string getLastName();
int getAge();
int getTelNum();
Address* getAddress();
int getNumAddrs();

void displayPerson();
void addAddress(Address &newAddr);

Person& operator =(const Person &RHS);


};

Person::Person()                                //default
{
firstName = "John";
lastName = "Doe";
age = -1;
telNum = -1;

numAddrs = 0;               //current number of addresses for this person

addrs = new Address*[10](); //throws error, won't compile
//new dynamic array of pointers, initialize to NULL

}

Person::Person(string first, string last, int y, int t)
{                                               //constructor to  initialize              Person
firstName = first;
lastName = last;
age = y;
telNum = t;

numAddrs = 0;                   //current number of addresses for this     person

addrs = new Address*[10](); throws error, won't compile
//new dynamic array of pointers, initialize to NULL

}


Person::Person(const Person &p)     //copy constructor
{
this->firstName = p.firstName;
this->lastName = p.lastName;
this->age = p.age;
this->telNum = p.telNum;
this->numAddrs = p.numAddrs;


delete [] addrs;        //delete previous dynamically allocated memory

addrs = new Address*[10](); //throws error, won't compile
//new dynamic array of pointers,     initialize to NULL

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)    //copy addresses to new object
{
this->addrs[i] = p.addrs[i];
}

}
```

Comment: is `addrs = *new Address*[10]();` how it actually appears in your code or did you add the `*`s for emphasis?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) delete [] addrs;` You are attempting to delete the same pointer 10 times. The first time it works, the second time it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Please don't comment out the part of the code that you're asking about. The SO code highlighter dims comments, making it hard to see the code that's most important to your question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The first time doesn't work, either, because `addrs` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: yes, the *new Address*[10](); is how it's in the code. it threw an error and recommended a fix of adding another *

Comment: sorry, the for loop isn't in use anymore. that was a leftover from an attempt to fix.

Comment: my apologies for the comment issue. didn't realize.

Comment: in the dynamic version of the program, i used  addrs as a pointer

Comment: @Barmar You are supposed to mentally comment parts that treat it as an array, and uncomment those that treat it as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`addrs` is not a pointer, it's an array. You don't need to allocate space for it with `new`, because its memory is allocated as part of the class object. It's an array of pointers, so you need to allocate memory for each element in the constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addrs[i] = new Address;
}
```

Then in the destructor, you need to delete each of these addresses.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete addrs[i];
}
```

However, there's a problem. Your assignment operator copies all the `addrs[i]` from the src to the destination. So now you have two `Person` objects with pointers to the same `Address` objects. If either of them gets destructed, it will free all the `Address` objects, and then the other `Person` will have invalid pointers in its `addrs` array.

It's not clear why you need an array of pointers instead of just an array of `Address` objects:

```
Address addrs[10];
```

Then you don't need to use `new` or `delete`.

Also, in modern C++ it's generally considered better to use containers like `std::vector`. You can also use smart pointer classes to deal with sharing the same pointer among multiple containers.

Comment: //Address* addrs; is a pointer, correct? That's what I'm using in the dynamic version of the program. The assignment specifies that we must use an array of pointers. The program functions correctly without them, but I'm trying to implement them for this particular assignment.

Comment: In the question you have `Address * addrs[10]`. That's an array of 10 pointers.

Comment: If you need a dynamic array of pointers, it should be `Address **addrs`.

Comment: Correct. That's what I'm intending here. But I run into issues when I attempt to allocate dynamically.

Comment: You need to do `addrs = new Address*[10]` and then a loop that sets `addrs[i] = new Address`.

Comment: That's what I did here: addrs = *new Address*[10](); //new dynamic array of pointers,     initialize to NULL

Comment: You shouldn't have `*` before `new`.

Comment: And it doesn't initialize them to `NULL`.

Comment: Could you repost the code in the question, without commenting out the parts that are important?